# Polymorphic Association and Nested Attributes: :error=>:blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to save a deeply nested form. There are three different models: Applications, Applicants, and Addresses. Addresses are polymorphic, as both Applications and Applicants can have them. These are the params that I'm sending:

```
{"application"=>{
    "loan_type"=>"purchase",
    "loan_amount"=>2500000,
    "borrower_attributes"=>{
        "first_name"=>"Test",
        "middle_name"=>"Test",
        "last_name"=>"Test",
        "birthdate"=>"01/01/1970",
        "phone"=>"1231231234",
        "email"=>"test@me.com",
        "marital_status"=>"married",
        "address_attributes"=>{
            "street_address"=>"xxxx Mission Street",
            "city"=>"San Francisco",
            "state"=>"CA",
            "zip"=>xxxxx
        }
    }
}}
```

When this is sent in my request, I'm getting the following response:

```
<Address id: nil, street_address: "1045 Mission Street", city: "San Francisco", state: "CA", zip: 94103, addressable_type: "Applicant", addressable_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

And the following error message:

```
@messages={:"borrower.address.addressable"=>["must exist"]}, @details={"borrower.address.addressable"=>[{:error=>:blank}]}
```

Why is it that I can't set the nested attributes? What do I need to fix to make this work?

Here are my relevant files:

**Application.rb**

```
class Application < ApplicationRecord
    before_save :assign_addresses!
    belongs_to :borrower, class_name: 'Applicant'
    belongs_to :coborrower, class_name: 'Applicant', optional: true
    has_one :address, as: :addressable

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :borrower
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :coborrower
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
end
```

**Applicant.rb**

```
class Applicant < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :applications
    has_one :address, as: :addressable
    validates_presence_of :first_name, :last_name, :phone, :email, :birthdate

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
end
```

**Address.rb**

```
class Address < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :addressable, polymorphic: true
    validates_presence_of :street_address, :city, :state, :zip
end
```

**Applications_Controller.rb**

```
class Api::ApplicationsController < ApplicationController

    ...

    def create
        @application = Application.new(application_params)

        if @application.save
            render json: @application, status: :created
        else
            render json: @application.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
        end
    end

    private

    def application_params
        params.require(:application).permit(:loan_type, :loan_amount, borrower_attributes: [:first_name, :middle_name, :last_name, :birthdate, :phone, :email, :ssn, :marital_status, address_attributes: [:street_address, :city, :state, :zip]])
    end
end
```

Answer (score 6):

Found the issue. Things worked fine after adding `optional: true` to the `Address` `belongs_to`. This is a new Rails 5 convention. I remembered to put it on my coborrower, but not there. Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Thanks Louis! This totally helps after searching forever to find the solution.

Comment: this work for me. But im still curious why this error didn't occur earlier on my other form.

Answer (score 0):

just build like this:

```
{"application"=>{
"loan_type"=>"purchase",
"loan_amount"=>2500000,
"applications_borrower_attributes"=>{"0"=>{
    "first_name"=>"Test",
    "middle_name"=>"Test",
    "last_name"=>"Test",
    "birthdate"=>"01/01/1970",
    "phone"=>"1231231234",
    "email"=>"test@me.com",
    "marital_status"=>"married"},
    "borrowers_address_attributes"=>{"0"=>{
        "street_address"=>"xxxx Mission Street",
        "city"=>"San Francisco",
        "state"=>"CA",
        "zip"=>xxxxx
     }
    }
  }
}}
```

Comment: No luck. Also, why did you include the "0"s?

Comment: That's how it is generated on forms with nested attributes @LouisCruz